# My webview video works on emulator but no on device

Tags: java, android, webview, android-emulator

I'm working on a WebRTC webview project. I'm playing a video with camera and microphone permission.  The Video works on emulator but not on phone.Buttons come in, camera turns on but the video does not appear. Leaves on white screen.

API levels are the same both API 28.

My codes here

initview()

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb);
        mWebView.requestFocus();
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebChromeClientCustomPoster chromeClient = new WebChromeClientCustomPoster();
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(chromeClient);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionRequest(final PermissionRequest request) {


                MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        request.grant(request.getResources());

                    }// run
                });// MainActivity

            }// onPermissionRequest
        });// setWebChromeClient


        mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
I added

```
mWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false)
```

and application works fine.